# Can't require googleapis with Parcel.js

Tags: javascript, parceljs

Checking here to see if anyone has experience using Parcel bundler and working with Googles api.

I'm building a website that will allow for people to upload files to a shared Google drive folder so I began looking into Googles api but I couldn't even get started because of problems when requiring googleapis in my javascript file.

When I run parcel index.html the following happens:

- a whole lot of warnings saying that it couldn't load googleapis source maps.
- ERROR that it "cannot resolve dependency "http2".

I've been troubleshooting this for a couple of days now with no progress at all and I really can't find anyone mentioning this.

Ive been using Parcel for a long time and it would be a shame to have to put Parcel aside just to get this thing with Googleapis working...

Thanks in advance!

Edit: forgot to include my code which is:

```
const google = require('googleapis')
```

I've also tried an import statement instead with the same result from Parcels compiler.

Googleapis is installed via npm before I'm doing this of course.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include as many relevant code examples as you can so we can help you better. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Literally here its just the one line to require the api which is:
const google = require('googleapis');